# Android NullPointerException in ItemDetail Fragment when setting title

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception

I don't know why but I get reports that many of my users get a `NullPointerException` in This line: 
`appBarLayout.setTitle("אזעקה (" + mItem.datetime + ")");`

I've tried many things to catch this exception but I just can't figure out how it reaches this line and gets a `NullPointerException`.

First I made sure that `appBarLayout` isn't null. Then I checked that my `mItem.datetime` does contain the datetime that it should.

Here is my code:

```
    mItem = AlertsDetails.items_map.get(getArguments().getString(ARG_ITEM_ID));

    Activity activity = this.getActivity();

    if (mItem == null || mItem.datetime == null)
    {
        activity.finish();
    }

    CollapsingToolbarLayout appBarLayout = (CollapsingToolbarLayout) activity.findViewById(R.id.toolbar_layout);
    if (appBarLayout != null) {
        appBarLayout.setTitle("אזעקה (" + mItem.datetime + ")");
        appBarLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.mipmap.alert_background);
    }
```

What did I miss here? How is that possible that both `appBarLayout` and `mItem.datetime` aren't null but yet the `setTitle` method creates a `NullPointerException`?

These are the error logs I get:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2955)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3030)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11 (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1696)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:105)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:164)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:6938)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (Zygote.java:327)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1374)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: 
  at com.morha.cumtaalerts.fragments.ItemDetailFragment.onCreate (ItemDetailFragment.java:63)
  at android.support.v4.app.Fragment.performCreate (Fragment.java:2328)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState (FragmentManager.java:1379)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.addToFirstInLastOut (FragmentTransition.java:1188)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.calculateFragments (FragmentTransition.java:1071)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransition.startTransitions (FragmentTransition.java:115)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether (FragmentManager.java:2379)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute (FragmentManager.java:2337)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions (FragmentManager.java:2244)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchStateChange (FragmentManager.java:3255)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentManager.java:3205)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated (FragmentController.java:195)
  at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.onStart (FragmentActivity.java:597)
  at android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart (AppCompatActivity.java:177)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart (Instrumentation.java:1340)
  at android.app.Activity.performStart (Activity.java:7191)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2918)
```

Thank you!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a NullPointerException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-nullpointerexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `return;` after you finish the `Activity`:

```
if (mItem == null || mItem.datetime == null)
{
    activity.finish();
    return;
}
```

Comment: That's my best guess. You should always add `return;` after you call `finish()` on an `Activity`, because the code after this line might still run and you'll get crashes like this.